# Find one cell inside a string and then populate another cell based off of that

Tags: excel, vba, search, find

I have a basic financial spreadsheet that I am trying to make even nicer.  I have a table that looks like this:

> | Description | Category | Amount
>
> | 2341234 Chick-fil-a | Eating Out | 5.89
>
> | 11234 Redbox/Georgetown | Entertainment | 1.21

And another table that looks like this:

> | Name | Category |
>
> | Chick-fil-a | Eating out |
>
> | Redbox | Entertainment |

I want to find the strings from the first column of the second table in the first column of the first table and automaically populate the second column of the first table. I am pretty sure I can find the position of the string by doing a {=find(2ndSheet!A:A,1stSheetA:A)} or something of the like, but I have no idea how to populate another cell based off of that.

Does it have to be a macro?

Comment: If you can sort alphabetically first, you can use `=VLOOKUP()` inside the cell formula.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think vlookup is good for multiple occurances.  The first table is a list of all transactions in a month the second table is just a "helper" table I created for the most common transactions.  I may eat at Chick-fil-a multiple times in a month (it's good chicken!). Also I don't know how to combine vlookup with =find(). because I need to find Chick-fil-a inside a string that contains other transactional info.

Comment: I see, the first column of table 1 is "##### Name", not just "Name".  Yeah, it would probably have to be a very convoluted `=IF(FIND())` formula to do it outside of a macro.

Comment: Can you just separate the Description column into two, with the number and the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit ugly but seems to work. It handles the situation where your description may not necessarily match the lookup table (for instance, with Redbox | Redbox/Georgetown). Replace the `[Lookup_Table]` with the absolute range of your lookup table, and enter as an array formula (`Control+Shift+Enter`):

```
=INDEX([Lookup_Table],MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERR((FIND([Lookup_Table],A2)))),0),2)
```

As for what it's doing:

```
=INDEX(
        [Lookup_Table],
        MATCH(
            TRUE,
            NOT(ISERR((FIND([Lookup_Table],A2)))),
            0),
         2)
```

It's using an `INDEX` formula with the [Lookup_Table] as the base range. For the row to match, it looks for instances where running the `FIND` formula using the current cell does not cause an error. So in the case of `Redbox`, you'd get an array like `{#VALUE!, 7}`. You then set the values to `TRUE/FALSE` based on whether they are errors, and then flip them so that non-errors are `True`. You then match the `TRUE` condition against that array, and a hit will return the row number in your lookup table. You then use that row number and column 2 to find the corresponding value.

Again, that is not a pretty one (and there is probably a better way to handle all of your cases), but it seems to work in my extremely exhaustive test of three rows :)

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. I think it's fairly elegant.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! Ha, I say that because I've come up with things before that I thought were okay, and then immediately been blown away by some wicked solution from one of the Excel gurus on this site :)

Comment: @DougGlancy And there is one of those gurus now :) Thanks Doug!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first table is starts in column `A`, substituting this formula starting in `B2` should find the value for you.

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2,1)),[Range of Helper Table],2,FALSE)
```

You'll need to substitute `[Range of Helper Table]` with the actual range. Make sure you use absolute references using $, for example: `2ndSheet!A$2:B$20`. so that you can copy and paste.

Comment: I think this is assuming that the string I need to find is always at the start of the cell? Which isn't necessarily true.  Either way I couldn't get this to work, but didn't try too hard since the above answer worked for me.  Thanks though!

Comment: Actually, it was assuming that the string you need to find is always at the end after the first space. as in xxxxx space then your string. but no matter, glad the other answer worked for you.